# Как отсортировать точки по увеличению их удаленности от начала координат с помощью лямбда выражений?

Tags: java, сортировка, объекты, arraylist, лямбда-выражение

**Условие задачи:** *Программа получает на вход целое число N, далее следуют N пар значений x, y - координаты текущей точки. Необходимо выстроить все точки по увеличению их удаленности от начала координат и вывести отсортированный список точек на экран в формате: (1; 2)
(2: 7)*...

Sample Input 1:

5

1 2

3 7

-2 3

1 1

3 5

Sample Output 1:

(1; 1)

(1; 2)

(-2; 3)

(3; 5)

(3; 7)

Есть формула для определения расстояния точки от начала координат: квадратный корень из (x^2 + y^2). Вроде бы (но не точно), саму формулу в коде я воспроизвожу правильно, но отрабатывает сортировка не так как нужно. Самое главное, я не понимаю каким образом происходит сортировка. Статей в интернете про лямбда и компараторы много, но примеры какие-то простые и вообще о другом. Поэтому очень хочется,по возможности, чтобы мне ***"разжевали"*** механику работы сортировки с лямбда выражением на моём примере. Вот мой код:

```
public class Point {
int x, y;
public Point(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "(" + x + "; " + y + ")";
}
```

}

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = in.nextInt();
    ArrayList <Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList <Point> points = new ArrayList<>();
    int count = 0;
    while (count != n * 2){
        list.add(in.nextInt());
        count++;
    }
    count = 0;
    int count2 = 0;
    while (count != n){
        points.add(new Point(list.get(count2),list.get(count2 + 1)));
        count ++;
        count2 += 2;
    }
    Collections.sort(points, (o1, o2) -> (int) Math.sqrt((o1.x)^2 + (o1.y)^2));
        for (Point p:points) {
        System.out.println(p);
    }
```

Как это вижу я: o1 - первый объект, o2 - второй, и их как бы нужно сравнить. Ок, у меня есть массив с пятью объектами ( (1 2) - первый, (3 7) - второй и т.д.) Но мне нужно проводить вычисления (согласно формуле) не между объектами массива, получается, а между x и у, т.е. между параметрами одного объекта... Если так, то зачем мне в параметрах выражения два объекта (о1 и о2). И я не уверен, что о1.х - это х ( 1, 3, -2, 1, 3), а о1.у - это у (2, 7, 3, 1, 5). Вообщем, как видите, я совсем ничего не понимаю здесь и совсем запутался.

Comment: Обратите внимание на знак "галочка" слева от ответов на Ваши вопросы. Этот знак сделан для Вас. Пользуйтесь.

Comment: Спасибо! Т. е. правильно я понимаю, что о1.х - это 1, о1.у - это 2, о2.х - 3 и о2.у - 7, в моём случае?

Comment: Не понял. У Вас в примере пять точек. Точки, попарно сравниваемые во время сортировки, могут быть любыми из этого набора.

Comment: Понял, спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Collections.sort(points, (o1, o2) -> o1.x*o1.x + o1.y*o1.y - o2.x*o2.x - o2.y*o2.y);
```